# Generate JSON-tree-object from table containing paths

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, tree

Given a table that contains paths/nodes of a tree structure which is unknown:

```
| id | path_id | node
| 1  | p1      | n1
| 2  | p1      | n2
| 3  | p1      | n3
| 4  | p2      | n1
| 5  | p2      | n2
| 6  | p2      | n4
```

The corresponding tree structure would be:

```
    n1 
   /  
  n2
 /  \
n3   n4
```

Is it possible to generate a JSON-object for this tree using SQL and PostgreSQL-functions?

Comment: Not sure how you structured the tree in your db; consider using a self-referencing `parent_id`, or a modified pre-order traversal http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: I don't understand how that node list translates to that graph. It doesn't look like a conventional edge-list.

Comment: Ordered by `id` each path consists of several nodes and edges between these nodes, e.g. path `p1` consists of the nodes `n1`, `n2` and `n3` in this specific order. The first node of a path is always the root node of the tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have a list of paths, where parts overlap.

#### Update 2024

With `jsonb` and `jsonb_object_agg()`, producing a denser result where each edge is one key/value pair.

`jsonb` removes duplicate key values out of the box. No `DISTINCT` required:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_object_agg(node, parent) AS edges
FROM  (
   SELECT node, lag(node) OVER (PARTITION BY path_id ORDER BY id) AS parent
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY parent NULLS FIRST, node  -- ORDER BY optional
   ) sub;
```

[`jsonb_object_agg_strict()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.16.1.1.1) also removes objects with null values, effectively trimming a dangling edge at the root:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_object_agg_strict(node, parent) AS edges
FROM  (
   -- same as above
   ) sub;
```

#### Original answer 2014

Legacy `json` solution. First remove duplicate edges, as `json` keeps all objects, even duplicate keys.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       node, lag(node) OVER (PARTITION BY path_id ORDER BY id) AS parent
FROM   tbl
ORDER  BY parent NULLS FIRST, node;  -- ORDER BY optional
```

`parent` is NULL for the root node.  You may want to remove this "non-edge" from the result.
Then, to *"generate a JSON-object for this tree"* you could use [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#id-1.5.8.27.5.2.4.13.1.1.1):

```sql
SELECT json_agg(sub) AS edges
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT
          node, lag(node) OVER (PARTITION BY path_id ORDER BY id) AS parent
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY parent NULLS FIRST, node  -- ORDER BY optional
   ) sub;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sn02-vcJ)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/74bd2/4)</sub>